# Error when parsing uppercase, but no error when parsing lowercase java

Tags: java, parsing

so my code is a program to tell whether water is temperature, gaseous or solid at certain temperatures, followed by the unit (Fahrenheit or Celsius).

The code works for units 'F', 'f', 'c', but not uppercase 'C'.

```
    public static void stateOfWater() {
    Scanner inputTempString = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter temperature: ");
    String temperatureString = inputTempString.nextLine().trim();
    String unit = temperatureString.substring(temperatureString.length()-1);
    unit = unit.toLowerCase();
    temperatureString = temperatureString.replace(unit,"");
    double temperature =  Double.parseDouble(temperatureString);

        if ( (temperature <= 0 && unit.equals("c")) || (temperature <= 32 && unit.equals("f")) ) {
            System.out.println("The state of the water is: solid (ice). ");
        }

        if (  ( (0.0 <= temperature && temperature < 100) && unit.equals("c")  ) || (((32 <= temperature && temperature < 212) && unit.equals("f")))) {
            System.out.println("The state of the water is: liquid. ");
        }

        if ((temperature > 100 && unit.equals("c")) || (temperature > 212 && unit.equals("f")))  {
            System.out.println("The state of the water is: gaseous. ");
        }
    }
```

I get this error when I try to input a temperature that contains uppercase C:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "43C"
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:543)
at lab2.Lab.stateOfWater(Lab.java:13)
at lab2.main.main(main.java:5)
```

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: You analysis of the problem is incorrect. You are replacing 'c' with '' to get the temprature. So '43C' will yield '43C' and this will fail to convert to number

Comment: The problematic code is `unit = unit.toLowerCase(); temperatureString = temperatureString.replace(unit,"");` For input `43C`, `unit` becomes `c`, but then you attempt to replace out `c`, which doesn't even exist in the `temperatureString`. I suggest lowercasing the whole `temperatureString` first, then chop off the unit character.

Comment: I doubt it works with uppercase `F` right now, since it has the same issue where you try to remove the lowercase `unit` from the still uppercased `temperatureString `..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why do I get this exception?**

You are converting the unit to lowercase and then replacing the lowercased string by an empty one. If your string was `43C` it would try to replace `c` by an empty string ... Well, that doesn't work, of course.

You should first cut off the unit from the temperature string *and then* convert the unit to lowercase.

```
String input = inputTempString.nextLine().trim();
String unit = input.substring(input.length() - 1).toLowercase();
double temperature = Double.parseDouble(input.substring(0, input.length() - 1));
```

**But why does `43F` work, while `43C` does not?**

The reason that it actually worked for uppercase F, is that the letter F is part of the floating point literal, as mentioned by the documentation of [Double.parseDouble(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) which in turn refers to [Double.valueOf(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)), which in turn refers to the [Java Language Specification § 3.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2), which refers to this token as the `FloatTypeSuffix` token.

---

Also, I suggest a different approach.

I would have parsed the input an converted it to a standardized unit, for example Celsius, and then for the piece of code responsible for the printing of the state of the water, I only had to write `if` statements with one or two comparisons. For example, instead of your `if` statement, for example:

```
(((0.0 <= temperature && temperature < 100) && unit.equals("c")  ) || (((32 <= temperature && temperature < 212) && unit.equals("f"))))
```

I would have something shorter:

```
String state = "";
if (temperature < 0) {
    state = "solid (ice)";
}
else if (temperature < 100) {
    state = "liquid";
}
else {
    state = "gaseous";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Mts mts mts

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not even need an unit! Just check last character of the given string and if it is 'F' or 'f', then subtract `32` to make degree in Celsius.

```
public static void stateOfWater() {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Enter temperature (e.g. 35F or 35C): ");
        String str = scan.nextLine().trim();
        double degree = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
        degree = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(str.length() - 1)) == 'F' ? degree : ((degree - 32) * 5) / 9;
        String state = Double.compare(degree, 0) <= 0 ? "solid (ice)" : Double.compare(degree, 100) < 0 ? "liquid" : "gaseous";
        System.out.println("The state of the water is: " + state + '.');
    }
}
```

Comment: This yields incorrect results. Not only the *intercept* between those scales is different, also the *slope*.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thanks, forgot about it. Fixed.